When does "helm upgrade" upgrade?
I'm new to Helm, so this probably has "you're doing it wrong" written all over it. So please be patient.
I'm currently trying to tweak the templates of an existing chart (not just the values), and I pulled the chart to a local directory from an external git repo. I'm experimenting with Minikube for now, because testing your changes locally at first is good.
So I made my changes, and tried to inspect the proposed changes to my own private cluster, with:
helm upgrade -i --force --values ~/myown.values.yaml  --dependency-update --dry-run  release-name ./charts/release-name -n a-new-namespace --create-namespace
..only to see my changes not take effect in the resulting manifests.
Is this the correct workflow? What else should I be doing?


only to see my changes not take effect in the resulting manifests.

The problem is probably caused by the --dry-run option, which simulates an upgrade.
From the helm upgrade documentation:
--dry-run string[="client"]
Simulate an install. If --dry-run is set with no option being specified or as --dry-run=client, it will not attempt cluster connections. Setting --dry-run=server allows attempting cluster connections.

Nope, didn't change a thing. When does an edited template actually get used to construct a deployment?

@AckThpfft are you sure there are actually any changes to br deployed? And that you are pointing to the right cluster? Check the documentation link I posted. Run helm template to see the generated resources, and take a good look at the logs when running helm upgrade.

One thing I know for sure: changes won't be deployed when using the dry-run option

I just tried an uninstall/install cycle. Still nothing.
It's as if my local copy is just being ignored.. maybe I need to add the local repo?
